# Most of 1TB Drive Space Being Wasted

Tags: partitioning, hard-drive, disk-usage

I'm really getting fed up with my system telling me that space is nearly used up, when I know that my 1TB HDD is mostly **empty** (downloads fail, can't save my work, etc.).  Emptying trash and running **BleachBit** offer only **temporary** solutions.  Can you please tell me there's a real solution that won't involve re-installing Ubuntu...yet again?  I've grown quite wary of **partitions** at this point.  Thanks.

[image: GParted Output]
Output from `ls -al /etc/grub.d` :

```
total 100
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root  4096 Dec 13 14:23 .
drwxr-xr-x 132 root root 12288 Jan 12 08:32 ..
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root root 10046 Feb  7  2019 00_header
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root root  6258 Mar  4  2018 05_debian_theme
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root root 12693 Mar  4  2018 10_linux
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root root 11298 Mar  4  2018 20_linux_xen
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root root  1992 Jan 28  2016 20_memtest86+
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root root   559 Oct 27 08:51 25_custom
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root root 12059 Mar  4  2018 30_os-prober
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root root  1418 Mar  4  2018 30_uefi-firmware
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root root   214 Mar  4  2018 40_custom
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root root   216 Mar  4  2018 41_custom
-rw-r--r--   1 root root   483 Mar  4  2018 README
```

Output from `grep -i menuentry /etc/grub.d/25_custom`:

```
menuentry "EFI/BOOT/bkpbootx64.efi" {
menuentry "EFI/BOOT/fbx64.efi" {
menuentry "EFI/ubuntu/fwupx64.efi" {
menuentry "EFI/ubuntu/mmx64.efi" {
```

[image: Disk Space Error Msg.]

cat /etc/fstab

```
#   file system     mount point     type     options     dump     pass   
# / was on /dev/sdc5 during installation 
UUID=6dc63d7f-10a6-4a7b-8544-160bd90656e9 / ext4 errors=remount-ro 0 1 
# /boot/efi was on /dev/sda1 during installation 
#UUID=8005-7FBB /boot/efi vfat umask=0077 0 1 
UUID=8005-7FBB /boot/efi vfat defaults 0 1
/swapfile none swap sw 0 0
```

joe@joe-MS-7B38:~/Desktop/QB64$ df -h

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev            3.9G     0  3.9G   0% /dev
tmpfs           800M  2.1M  798M   1% /run
/dev/sdb5        17G   16G  231M  99% /
tmpfs           4.0G   91M  3.9G   3% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.0M  4.0K  5.0M   1% /run/lock
tmpfs           4.0G     0  4.0G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/loop0      4.3M  4.3M     0 100% /snap/gnome-calculator/536
/dev/loop1      4.3M  4.3M     0 100% /snap/gnome-calculator/544
/dev/loop2      1.0M  1.0M     0 100% /snap/gnome-logs/81
/dev/loop3       15M   15M     0 100% /snap/gnome-characters/367
/dev/loop5      141M  141M     0 100% /snap/gnome-3-26-1604/98
/dev/loop6       45M   45M     0 100% /snap/gtk-common-themes/1353
/dev/loop7      1.0M  1.0M     0 100% /snap/gnome-logs/73
/dev/loop8       90M   90M     0 100% /snap/core/8268
/dev/loop11     157M  157M     0 100% /snap/gnome-3-28-1804/91
/dev/loop12     3.8M  3.8M     0 100% /snap/gnome-system-monitor/111
/dev/loop15      90M   90M     0 100% /snap/core/8213
/dev/loop16     203M  203M     0 100% /snap/vlc/1049
/dev/loop18     157M  157M     0 100% /snap/gnome-3-28-1804/110
/dev/loop17     141M  141M     0 100% /snap/gnome-3-26-1604/97
/dev/loop9      3.8M  3.8M     0 100% /snap/gnome-system-monitor/123
/dev/loop10     203M  203M     0 100% /snap/vlc/1397
/dev/loop4       15M   15M     0 100% /snap/gnome-characters/375
/dev/sda1       188M  7.2M  180M   4% /boot/efi
/dev/loop19      55M   55M     0 100% /snap/core18/1288
tmpfs           800M   52K  800M   1% /run/user/1000
/dev/sr0        6.0G  6.0G     0 100% /media/joe/DIRT
/dev/sda2       917G   12G  859G   2% /media/joe/695a1d1e-fd7d-4d22-9b2d-474c06128758
/dev/loop20      55M   55M     0 100% /snap/core18/1650
/dev/loop13      45M   45M     0 100% /snap/gtk-common-themes/1440
tmpfs           800M   16K  800M   1% /run/user/120

joe@joe-MS-7B38:~/Desktop/QB64$ sudo blkid

/dev/sda1: UUID="8005-7FBB" TYPE="vfat" PARTUUID="27a1ee8f-f7d1-4950-abbd-9e8f108b5464"
/dev/sda2: UUID="695a1d1e-fd7d-4d22-9b2d-474c06128758" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="672863c7-133e-46f1-b73b-4f6bef6e1ff5"
/dev/sdb1: UUID="C040B0ED40B0EB74" TYPE="ntfs" PARTUUID="e8900690-01"
/dev/sdb5: UUID="6dc63d7f-10a6-4a7b-8544-160bd90656e9" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="e8900690-05"
/dev/loop0: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop1: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop2: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop3: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop4: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop5: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop6: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop7: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop8: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop9: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop10: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop11: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop12: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop13: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop15: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop16: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop17: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop18: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop19: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop20: TYPE="squashfs"
```

[image]
[image]

```
sudo fdisk -l /dev/sda
Disk /dev/sda: 931.5 GiB, 1000204886016 bytes, 1953525168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 4C785F47-BD76-4FB3-BCB1-4C0011813BF4

Device      Start        End    Sectors   Size Type
/dev/sda1    2048     391167     389120   190M EFI System
/dev/sda2  391168 1953521663 1953130496 931.3G Linux filesystem

Disk /dev/sdb: 931.5 GiB, 1000204886016 bytes, 1953525168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0xe8900690

Device     Boot      Start        End    Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/sdb1  *            63 1918130209 1918130147 914.7G  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sdb2       1918132222 1953523711   35391490  16.9G  5 Extended
/dev/sdb5       1918132224 1953523711   35391488  16.9G 83 Linux
```

Comment: When does the system complain about a lack of storage? What is the EXACT message?

Comment: I am no expert and do not know if it matters, but only your EFI partition has a mount point.  I usually will use a partition like your sda2 as /(root) and sda4 as /home(ext4 format).  Do you have downloads set to go to sda4?

Comment: I'm no expert so maybe I'm completely wrong, but it seems that you could extend your /dev/sd4 partition to make use of those unallocated 195.43GiB.

Comment: @CélestinTaramarcaz other than the fact that it's a NTFS partition, /dev/sda4 is not where the problem is.

Comment: @crip659 /dev/sda4 is labelled as "Storage", so /home is on /dev/sda2.

Comment: @heynnema  did not write it property, was trying give him an example of my partition setup, I know some use a NTFS partition for data storage.

Comment: @crip659 yes, NTFS partition is good in a dual-boot environment with Windows... otherwise in a Ubuntu only environment, ext4 is a better choice.

Comment: I'm waiting to see the exact message again.  There are things I haven't yet tried, and things I've tried (sometimes based on advice received here) which have led to my having to use Boot Repair, or even re-install the whole OS.  So, naturally, I'm hesitant to try anything.  I'll consider all of this info carefully, thanks.  I certainly hope it's as simple as resizing a partition.  When I've tried to do it before, it wouldn't let me.

Comment: @JoeJ looking at your screenshot, it's no wonder that you're a little afraid of partitions. However, I've left you two choices to consider, and it's not difficult in either case. If my answer ends up being helpful, please remember to accept it. Thanks!

Comment: Now, to decide what's important enough to back up!

Comment: Before you back up and wipe stuff out, please type `sudo du / -h --max-depth=1 2>/dev/null`, grab a coffee and then report the results. This will tell us how all your disk partition is allocated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Make sure that you have a good backup of your important Ubuntu files, as this procedure can corrupt or lose data.

Keep these things in mind:

- always start the entire procedure with issuing a `swapoff` on any mounted swap partitions, and end the entire procedure with issuing a `swapon` on that same swap partition
- a **move** is done by pointing the mouse pointer at the center of a partition and dragging it left/right with the hand cursor
- a **resize** is done by dragging the left/right side of a partition to the left/right with the directional arrow cursor
- if any partition can't be **moved/resized** graphically, you may have to manually enter the specific required numeric data (don't do this unless I instruct you to)
- you begin any **move/resize** by right-clicking on the partition in the lower pane of the main window, and selecting the desired action from the popup menu, then finishing that action in the new **move/resize** window

**Do the following...**

---

**Note**: If this is NOT a dual-boot environment with Windows, /dev/sda4 should be an ext4 partition, not NTFS.

**Note**: if the procedure doesn't work exactly as I outline, **STOP** immediately and **DO NOT** continue.

- boot to a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB
- start `gparted`
- **move** /dev/sda4 partition all the way right
- **resize** /dev/sda2 right side all the way right

  - adjust the final sizes of /dev/sda2 and /dev/sda4 if desired
- click the Apply icon

---

OR...

---

**Note**: Since it appears that you're not running a dual-boot with Windows...

- backup any important data from /dev/sda4
- if you have added a mount point for /dev/sda4 in /etc/fstab, comment it out

  - `sudo -H gedit /etc/fstab`
- boot to a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB
- start `gparted`
- delete /dev/sda4
- resize /dev/sda2 right side all the way right
- click the Apply icon
- reboot
- restore any /dev/sda4 data to your /home directory

---

**Update #1:**

- minor deviation to fix another problem

`sudo mv /etc/grub.d/25_custom ~/Desktop` # move file to desktop

`sudo update-grub` # update grub

`reboot` # marvel at your newer cleaner GRUB menu!

**Update #2:**

OP is actually booting to /dev/sdb5, and **that** is where we're running out of space!

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/103381/discussion-on-answer-by-heynnema-most-of-1tb-drive-space-being-wasted).